# oracle autoincrement with sequence and trigger is not working correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, sequence

here is my problemI have this code to make an autoincrement variable in oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE Korisnici
    (
        id_korisnika number PRIMARY KEY,
        ime_korisnika varchar2(200),
        prezime_korisnika varchar2(200),
        broj_telefona varchar2(30),
        adresa_korisnika varchar2(400)
    )
    /

create sequence test_seq
start with 1 
increment by 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Korisnici FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT test_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO :NEW.id_korisnika
  FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

If I start from begining everything works great, I have numbers as 1,2,3,4....
I close the program, open it again, so oracle database connection is once again started. I add one more input and I have numbers like 20,21,22,23...
I put program on my android and connect from different device, when I input one user I have 30,31,33,34...

Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

Thank you

EDIT:

Here is my proc for reading data from database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Citanje_korisnika( p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM Korisnici;
END;
```

I am a bit of newbie in oracle database.

Comment: If you commit each transaction then the sequence is continuously increasing . What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying the SEQUENCE with NOCACHE will stop a session caching 20 numbers at a time and help.

```
create sequence test_seq
start with 1 
increment by 1
NOCACHE;
```

However, if you're hoping for a completely contiguous sequence this is very difficult to achieve - numbers taken from the sequence are "lost" if (for example) an insert is rolled back.

---

Based on your comment, I wonder if you're forgetting to COMMIT?

Comment: for example when I add one row from my php script everything is correct, then I go to sql plus and insert one row everything goes well too. But when I want to read with my php script all data I only get data inserted with php script...  I will test it a bit more your answer about nocache

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem. You have probably specified `cache 10` in your sequence creation script. If you change this to `nocache` it will help with the gaps, at the cost of a hit to performance, but they'll never go away completely as any rollbacks done, and killed inserts etc will use up values. Please see [this Ask Tom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441).

At the end of the day it shouldn't matter in the slightest. If you're relying on an unbroken sequence as the key of your table then you probably have a problem with your data rather than sequences.

Comment: @denonth, you haven't linked your trigger and your procedure so the proc tells us nothing. I'm inclined to agree with cagocowboy's edit to his answer.