# Oracle sequence - skipped numbers

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE SEQUENCE F_SQ  
START WITH 1  
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999  
MINVALUE 1  
NOCYCLE  
CACHE 20  
NOORDER;
```

I have a sequence created using the above script. Our nightly jobs use these sequences, so on the first day it used 1,2,3,4,5 and the next day it started with 21,22,23 .. and so on

I can understand it is happening because of the CACHE parameter.

Now the questions is

For three days it been skipping some numbers in between .

Will the sequence ever decide to use these skipped numbers?(from above example 6 to 20) , if so on what circumstance and is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: No, the sequence will keep increasing (or eventually CYCLE back to minvalue if you specify this), but sequences are NOT guaranteed to increment by 1 (which is a common misunderstanding).  And yes, the gaps are due to the CACHE

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle autoincrement with sequence and trigger is not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428212/oracle-autoincrement-with-sequence-and-trigger-is-not-working-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it would be due to cache parameter that the values are skipped. Some of the reasons as specified in the document may b because when a system failure occurs, all cached sequence values that have not been used in committed DML statements are lost. The potential number of lost values is equal to the value of the CACHE parameter.Always use NOCACHE  option if u want a contiguous sequence values irrespective of cases as specified above.

And for the last question, these sequences will not be used again unless if u have mentioned the CYCLE option in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, But i am seeing these sequences using old numbers, as you can see i have given NOCYCLE, yesterday i was running the same job thrice, Last value in sequence was 401, first time i ran the job it created 402, second time it created 391 and third time 392. fourth time i ran after few hours it created 403.

Comment: how can i prevent this behaviour, i am ok with it skipping as long as it keeps creating in increasing order.  Can i recreate the sequence and force it to run in an ascending order only , is there any such option?

Comment: Yes in that case recreate or alter the existing sequence with NOCACHE option. It would give you contiguous number.

Comment: You must have a RAC installation? Each node in your cluster will use it's own cache of 20 (or whatever value you set CACHE to.) Node 1 might get number 381 from the sequence and then cache numbers 382-400 for the next use within *that* node. Node 2 will get number 401 from the sequence and cache numbers 402-420. Depending on which node your job runs on, it will get a number either in 382-400 range or in 402-420 range. You can get around this if you create the sequence with ORDER rather than NOORDER, but it will cost performance as the two nodes needs to use locks to ensure the order.

Comment: Oh yea.. our test environments (where this scenario happened) is running in RAC mode but our PROD servers are NON-RAC, so that means i will always get sequence in increasing order.

Comment: i guess these are the only criteria would help solve the issue. Also please do accept the answer if satisfied.